# How to calculate $9^{47^{51}} \mod 67$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've looked at some other related things on here, but this seems a little more complicated with the double exponentiation. Is there a general algorithm to calculate $a^{c_1^{c_2^{...^{c_n}}}} \mod p$ or something?

Comment: Have you heard of Euler's theorem?

Comment: @Arthur I'll look into it, I'm only a beginner in math, so this is the first time I hear about it, thanks

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) and the scores of questions linked to that umbrella question. I would vote to close this as a dupe, but have promised not to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\phi(67)=66=2\cdot 3\cdot 11$$ and

By Fermat's Theorem, 
$$47^{51}\equiv47^{1}\equiv 47\pmod2$$
$$47^{51}\equiv47^{1}\equiv 47\pmod3$$
$$47^{51}\equiv47^{1}\equiv 47\pmod {11}$$

Thus, using Chinese Remainder 
$$47^{51}\equiv 47\pmod {66}$$

Thus, by Fermat' Little theorem:
$$9^{47^{51}}\equiv 9^{47}\equiv 3^{94}\equiv 3^{28}\equiv (-64)^{28}\equiv ((-4)^3)^{28}\equiv (-4)^{84}\equiv (-4)^{18}\equiv 4^{18}\equiv 2^{36}\equiv -2^3\equiv -8\pmod{67}$$
, where $2^{33}\equiv -1$ comes from the fact that $2^{33}=\left(\frac 2{67}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}8}$

Answer (score 2):

$67$ is a prime number, thus, Fermat's Theorem holds.

This implies

$$9^{66}=1 \pmod  {67} $$ you should resolve now $$ 47^{51} = ? \pmod {66}  $$

Consider that $66 = 2\cdot3\cdot11$, you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Please put braces around $51$ in $47^{51}$.   :-)

Comment: Yes, I was editing

Comment: Please check my edit to see a lot of nice features of latex :)

Answer (score 2):

First focus on $47^{51}$ in your example.  You must figure that out mod $66$, the latter number being the Euler totient of $67$.  Let $r$ be that residue and then attack $9^r$ modulo $67$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,
$$9^{47^{51}}=3^{2\cdot47^{51}}$$

As $\phi(67)=\lambda(67)=66,$
$$3^{2\cdot47^{51}}\equiv3^{2\cdot47^{51}\pmod{66}}\pmod{67}$$

As $(2\cdot47^{51},66)=2,$ let us find $47^{51}\pmod{33}$

As $\lambda(33)=\cdots=10,51\equiv1\pmod{10},$

$$47^{51}\equiv47^1\pmod{33}\equiv14$$

$$\implies2\cdot47^{51}\equiv14\cdot2\pmod{66}$$

$$\implies3^{2\cdot47^{51}}\equiv3^{28}\pmod{67}$$

Now $3^4\equiv14,3^8=(3^4)^2\equiv14^2\equiv-5$

$\implies3^{28}=3^4\cdot(3^8)^3\equiv14\cdot(-5)^3\equiv14\cdot9\equiv-8\equiv-8+67$

Comment: What is $\lambda(n)$?

Comment: @Emre wikipedia says it's Carmichael function

Comment: @Emre, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167616/explain-carmichaels-function-to-a-novice,  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html, OR  Carmichael_function

Comment: @OscarLanzi, $$\lambda(33)=(\lambda(11),\lambda(3))=(10,2)=10$$

Comment: Got rid of comment, thought $\lambda meant something else.