# What is variable c in Bezout's Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to learn Carmichael's function from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167635/513294).

I analyzed this rule:

> If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $a|bc$, then $a|c$.

If greatest common divisor of numbers a and b is 1 (if they are coprime) and a is divisible by b multiplied by c, then a is divisible by c.

But what is this c?

I thought it was the output of the gcd function. Thus, I substituted variables with prime numbers (where a=5, b=3, c=gcd(a,b)) and got this:

> If gcd(5, 3) = 1 and 5|3(1), then 5|1.

Now obviously, the statement above is incorrect since 5 is not evenly divisible by 3 and yet, 5 is divisible by 1.

Then, the author of the answer mentioned Bezout's Identity -

> $a$ and $b$ are coprime if and only if there exist $x$ and $y$ such
>   that $ax+by=1$. Multiplying through by $c$ we get $c = acx + bcy$.
>   Since $a$ divides both $acx$ and $bcy$ (the latter by virtue of
>   dividing $bc$), then $a$ divides $c$.

But, yet, how is variable c obtained?

Thank you!

Comment: The $c$ is just any integer in "this rule". If $a\mid bc$ with some $c$, then $a\mid c$ for coprime $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intersted to see how $c$ is linked to Bezout's theorem, consider that since:
$$a|bc\implies bc=ak $$

Since also:
$$\gcd(a,b)=1$$

for Bezout's theorem $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$ax+by=1 \implies acx+bcy=c \implies acx+aky=c \implies a(cx+ky)=c$$

Thus 
$$c|a \quad \square$$

Comment: Thank you! that got me one step forward!

Answer (score 1):

What the statement means is this: if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers, if $a$ and $b$ are co-prime, and if $a$ divides $bc$, then $a$ divides $c$.

Comment: Thank you! So as i understand, bc should always be equal to 1 for a to be divided by c.

Comment: @ShellRox No. What I wrote was that *if* $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and if $a\mid bc$, *then* $a$ divides $c$.